# Move cursor of JTextField or JComboBox to the start

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox, text-cursor

I have a `JTextField` with some text. When I click text field the cursor moves to the end of field. I want the cursor to move to the start of the field when it becomes focused.

I have the same problem with an editable `JComboBox`.

How can I achieve this cursor positioning on focus?

Comment: I mean I have editable JComboBox with any text in content , and when I click JComboBox I wnat to move marker to the start of editable JComboBox. By default it goes to the end of text field. When I said start of field I don't mean first item of drop down list.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  My confusion became sorted somewhat throughout the editing of that comment.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/**
* On gaining focus place the cursor at the start of the text.
*/
public class CursorAtStartFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JTextComponent) {
            JTextComponent comp = (JTextComponent) source;
            comp.setCaretPosition(0);
        } else {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.INFO,
                    "A text component expected instead of {0}",
                    source.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}

jTextField1.addFocusListener(new CursorAtStartFocusListener());
jComboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addFocusListener(new CursorAtStartFocusListener());
// Only one instance of CursorAtStartFocusListener needed.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command

> comp.setCaretPosition(index);

there index is caret position.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
JTextField t = new JTextField();
t.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
```